# How to change histogram color with buttons in plotly (python)?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, histogram, updates

[Inspired by this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69874081/how-to-update-histogram-nbins-with-buttons-in-plotly-python)

I would like to change the color of the bars, each time a button is clicked. It seems that the color of the bars just can't be updated. Does anyone have a hint on this? (Code below)

```
dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "age": [19, 18, 28, 33, 32],
        "bmi": [27.9, 33.77, 33.0, 22.705, 28.88],
        "children": [0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
    }
)
col_bins = {c: int(dataset[c].max() - dataset[c].min()) for c in dataset.columns}

fig = px.histogram(
    x=dataset["age"], nbins=col_bins["age"], color_discrete_sequence=["darkred"]
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [{"x": [dataset[c]], "nbinsx": bins}, {"xaxis.title": c}],
                }
                for c, bins in col_bins.items()
            ],
            "direction": "right",
            "type": "buttons",
            "x": 1,
            "y": 1.15,
        }
    ],
    xaxis_title="age",
    title_text="Histograms",
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added another entry to `{"x": [dataset[c]], "nbinsx": bins}` so that it looks like: `{"x": [dataset[c]], "nbinsx": bins, "marker.color": [marker_colors[i]]}`
where `marker_colors` is a list of colors I defined. This [forum post](https://community.plotly.com/t/switching-marker-colors-with-updatemenus/8509) was a useful resource.

Full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

dataset = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "age": [19, 18, 28, 33, 32],
        "bmi": [27.9, 33.77, 33.0, 22.705, 28.88],
        "children": [0, 1, 3, 0, 0],
    }
)

col_bins = {c: int(dataset[c].max() - dataset[c].min()) for c in dataset.columns}

marker_colors = ['#1f77b4','#ff7f0e','#2ca02c']

fig = px.histogram(
    x=dataset["age"], nbins=col_bins["age"]
)
fig.update_layout(
    updatemenus=[
        {
            "buttons": [
                {
                    "label": c,
                    "method": "update",
                    "args": [
                        {"x": [dataset[c]], "nbinsx": bins, "marker.color": [marker_colors[i]]},
                        {'xaxis.title': c},
                    ],
                }
                for i, (c, bins) in enumerate(col_bins.items())
            ],
            "direction": "right",
            "type": "buttons",
            "x": 1,
            "y": 1.15,
        }
    ],
    xaxis_title="age",
    title_text="Histograms",
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: good answer.... how did you make the GIF ?

Comment: @D.L. thanks! I used a google chrome extension called [Chrome Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-capture-gif-screen/ggaabchcecdbomdcnbahdfddfikjmphe)

Comment: @DerekO Thanks! It works. What I actually want to achieve, is to have the bars of the histogram colored by the different elements, so I use the "color" parameter. But the problem is that I can't get it to update with the new elements. Do you have any hint on this? Because you passed "marker.color" as a parameter label, which seems to me intuitive, since I do not see that as a parameter for histogram.

Comment: @DerekO, Take this simple example;

`import plotly.express as px`\

`df = px.data.tips()`\
`fig = px.histogram(df, x="day", color="smoker").update_xaxes(categoryorder='total descending')`\
`fig.show()`\

Can we update the "color" parameter of the histogram? Imagine in my example, the color values are much more than two, and should change each time I update the "x" parameter.